# No available gpu in the virtual machine. (Azure)

Tags: azure, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, nvidia

I create a virtual machine in Azure for training a machine learning model using tensor flow(python) with the following specification:

Image: NVIDIA GPU-Optimized VMI with vGPU driver

size: D4s_v3

System Operative: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

I'm trying accelerate the training process but don't recognizer the Nvidia/cuda.

I download the Nvidia toolkit manually with the follow command

`apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkitlsb_release -a`

but when I try to see the controllers with inxi show this.

`inxi -Gx`

Graphics:  Message: No Device data found.
Display: server: No display server data found. Headless machine? tty: 204x63
Message: Advanced graphics data unavailable in console for root.